# Can't view json file on jsonviewer.stack.hu

Tags: python, json

I've been trying to visualise this json with http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ , but i get an Invalid JSON variable error whenever I click on the viewer tab.
**here is the actual json**
`{'source': {'id': 'reuters', 'name': 'Reuters'}, 'author': None, 'title': "CRYPTOVERSE-Bitcoin could be laid low by miners' malady - Reuters", 'description': "Bitcoin miners are feeling the heat - and the pain's rippling downstream to pressure prices.", 'url': 'https://www.reuters.com/markets/europe/cryptoverse-bitcoin-could-be-laid-low-by-miners-malady-2022-02-22/', 'urlToImage': 'https://www.reuters.com/resizer/9nBpgfg7pSfpPQXnDcfMde9l3v0=/1200x628/smart/filters:quality(80)/cloudfront-us-east-2.images.arcpublishing.com/reuters/OXI44UUFUBOOBJGVTYCNM4IIBI.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2022-02-22T06:17:00Z', 'content': "Feb 22 (Reuters) - Bitcoin miners are feeling the heat - and the pain's rippling downstream to pressure prices.\r\nThe cryptocurrency's spectacular rally in 2021 drew thousands of entrants into mining,… [+4196 chars]"}`

Why does it give an error when i've retrieved the data with the requests.get() and converted it to json with json() method?

Thank you for your kind answers!

Comment: Its not valid json. You need **double quotes** for valid json.

Comment: I'd suggest calling `json.dumps` on your dict data, to return valid json you can use.

Answer (score 0):

well, double quotes didn't do job, but i just tried `json.dumps` -I had no idea it existed- and it worked! I still don't know why it worked since the double quotes didn't seem to affect the validity of the json, but i'll do some investigations. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Consider removing/edit the question as it's coming from bad json content